# WSDL Client Unable to Resolve Domain Name

Tags: java, dns, wsdl, nslookup

Recently i am working with DNS RR.I have DNS Server with domain Name configured with two Ip where apache httpd services are running...
DNS Server :xx.xx.xx.58,Domain Name:xxx.xxx.sam.com,httpdNode1 :xx.xx.xx.21,htttpdNode2 :xx.xx.xx.22.
From client machine xx.xx.xx.27 ping to xxx.xxx.sam.com working fine ,nslookup xxx.xxx.sam.com  also giving valid results  and wget to https:\xxx.xxx.sam.com:80\service?wsdl also working and returning success.

but in my java wsdl client when i try to access  https:\xxx.xxx.sam.com:80\service?wsdl its not able to resolve and saying unknown host.what is missed here?
As of now DNS Server is window based but all nodes having Redhat Linux OS

Comment: Can you post snippet of you WSDL, particularly the <soap:address> attributes and values. I also find it strange that HTTS is binded to port 80.

Comment: 80 i used just dummy here.my port is 10002 which is config  in httpd.conf ...which can be any as per my understanding         <soap:address location="https://xx.xx.xx.xxx:10002/...Service/services"/>